# How get values from key

Tags: json, angular, web-services

```
export class Installment {
    constructor(
        public isResurring: boolean,
        public isInstallment: boolean,
        public price: string,
        public sku: string
    ) { }

this.keys = Object.keys(this.paymentPlans);

   for(let key of this.keys){
        if(key == "A"){
            // how to get value and assign that value to above object

        }
}
```

i am getting keys A,B in an array

In angular 2 how to get values based on provided key (A or B)...  here value is an objects 
how to parse it into an model in angular 2

```
for(let key of this.keys){
        if(key == "A"){
            // how to get value and assign that value to object}}`
```

here is my json object

```
export class Installment {
    constructor(
        public isResurring: boolean,
        public isInstallment: boolean,
        public price: string,
        public sku: string
    ) { }
```

//Json Object

```
{"A":{"isInstallment":true,"isRecurring":true,"price":"4.0","sku":"abc"},
"B":{"isInstallment":false,"isRecurring":true,"price":"1.0","sku":"def"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Angular, this is related to Javascript.

```
const keys = ['A'];
const obj1 = {
  A: 'Some value',
  B: 'Some other value'
};
const obj2 = {};

for (let key of keys)
  obj2[key] = obj1[key]; // <---- This is the way to access an object property with a string

console.log(obj2); // {"A": "Some value"}
```

This code will assign the A property from obj1 into A property of obj2.

Comment: i am getting keys from  this.paymentPlans = this.productSummary.paymentPlans; this.keys = Object.keys(this.paymentPlans); for(let key of this.keys){ if(key == 'A') { //return associated key value }} That value should be converted to installment object

Comment: can someone help.. how to return associated key value

Comment: `for(let key of this.keys){ if(key == 'A') { return this.paymentPlans[key] }}`

Comment: But if youre looking for the property 'A' then just do this.paymentPlans.A

Comment: 'for(let key of this.keys){
        if(key == this.productPaymentPlan){
            obj2[this.productPaymentPlan] =  obj1[this.productPaymentPlan];
             
            console.log("^^^^^^^"+JSON.stringify(obj2));
        }
       
      }'  how to convert obj2 to export class Installment {
    constructor(
        public isResurring: boolean,
        public isInstallment: boolean,
        public price: string,
        public sku: string
    ) { }  ( in obj2 i am printing sting {"ir":{"isInstallment":true,"isRecurring":true,"price":"694.50","sku":"490105050"}}

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve can you be more specific?

Comment: as you said i am getting  console.log("^^^^^^^"+JSON.stringify(obj2)); i want obj2 convert to this.installment

Comment: yes how to convert SON.stringify(obj2) to `export class Installment {
    constructor(
        public isResurring: boolean,
        public isInstallment: boolean,
        public price: string,
        public sku: string
    ) { }`

Comment: So you want obj2 to be an instance of Installment?

Comment: yes obj2 values convert to be instance of installment

Comment: `obj2 = Object.assign(new Installment(), this.productPaymentPlan)` This will give you an instances of Installment with the properties of this.productPaymnentPlan

Comment: ` const obj2 ={};
      
      for(let key of this.keys){
        if(key == this.productPaymentPlan){
            obj2[this.productPaymentPlan] =  obj1[this.productPaymentPlan];
            this.installment =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.values(key.valueOf)));
            obj2 = Object.assign(new Installment(), this.productPaymentPlan);
            console.log("^^^^^^^"+JSON.stringify(this.installment));
            
        }
          
      }` if i do like that it is giving me error obj2 cannot assign because it is a constant

Comment: understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

but you can use angular forEach to do that

```
var k = 'A'
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
 if (k == key) {
   doSomething()
 }
})
```

Comment: can you please provide me correct syntax what i have to do in place of angular

Comment: can you please describe how to get value in do something

Comment: @user11703694 can you please add a working code snippet , because i cant understand your question . maybe you can post here and share link https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: const obj2 ={};
      
      for(let key of this.keys){
        if(key == this.productPaymentPlan){
            obj2[this.productPaymentPlan] =  obj1[this.productPaymentPlan];
            
            console.log("^^^^^^^"+JSON.stringify(obj2));
            
        }
          
      }